# Unable to Add Roles to Users (On Published Server Version)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, publishing

The company I work for has a ASP.NET MVC application that runs perfect when launched in Visual Studio (Local). However, once you publish it and launch it from the Client Server (you get to it by putting a link into a web browser). A problem with a security feature occurs. Specifically, an administrator can remove roles from users, but is unable to add new roles for users.
I found this: [Why won't my MVC project work after publishing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172304/why-wont-my-mvc-project-work-after-publishing-it)

I took from it a few things:

I changed

```
System.Web.Routing Copy Local = True
System.Web.Abstractions Copy Local = True
```

Along with that I even tried/changed “Only files needed to run the application” to “all” or “entire” (will change it back).

It didn’t seem to have an effect on the issue.

I really don’t have a lot of experience when it comes to MVC or for that matter, published applications. I am looking for direction on where the error might lie rather than specific answers.

Comment: Can you mention the error that happens when you try to add to add the role

Comment: There is no exception thrown or an application crash if that's what you are asking? The application is just unresponsive and the click action doesn't fire. I did go threw the application with break points (Local Version) and I did not see anything of suspicious nature.